# How to add certification to developer story with single date (and not a period)

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, developer-story

I may want to add a certificate, but I may want only the completion date to be entered while adding that (and I don't want to choose "Current"). There can be many instances when we are willing to add just one date to certification.

Comment: Certificates usually have an expiration date, don't they?

Comment: Well, some of them do, but it looks odd for a Developer Story to predict the future.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestion.

Funny thing, Certification items back in the day only included a single completion date, instead of both start/end dates. This was changed because we wanted to support time sensitive certifications too, so that expired certifications could be correctly represented. Unfortunately, our current model binds the absence of an end date to the item being "current", so users have to either provide an end date or check the "Is Current" checkbox.

But here's some good news: we are currently planning a lot of improvements to the Developer Story UX, including more flexibility to the way users inform dates and sort items. In the meantime, here's some workarounds you can use:

1. Use the same date as Start and End for your certification items
2. Create a `Milestone` item instead and set its category to Certification

[image: adding a milestone]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the workaround. We are looking forward to the changes you guys will add to Developer Story UX.