# Not able to add an end date to a milestone

Tags: support, developer-story

I'm a bit surprised not to be able to add an end date to a milestone in the "Developer Story" while this feature seems to be (or have been) possible (if I believe [this former answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339956/4094098)).

Do I miss something?

Comment: Surely a milestone would be a single point in time? The answer you link doesn't suggest otherwise.

Comment: Sure, it seems that I got confused reading the end of this answer, sorry. But why in this case the label is "Date started" and not something like "Release date" or another one that explicitly suggests that there can be only a single and unique date?